# The last eight digits of the binary development of $27^{1986}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, number-systems

> Find the last eight digits of the binary development of $27^{1986}$.

We define $v_p(x)$ such that if $v_p(x) = n$, then $p^n \mid x$ but $p^{n+1} \nmid x$. Now we see that if $n \geq 2$ is an integer and $r$ is even, if $v_2(3^r-1) = n$, then $v_2(3^{2r}-1) = n+1$. Otherwise if $n$ is odd then if $v_2(3^r-1) = n$, then $v_2(3^{2r}-1) = n+2$.

How do I continue from here?

Comment: Just compute $27^{1986} \pmod{256}$ and convert that to binary.

Comment: @T.Bongers Why $256$?

Comment: $256 = 2^8{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: If you wanted the last two decimal digits, you'd take the remainder mod $100 = 10^2$, right? Same principle....

Comment: @T.Bongers How do we find $27^{1986} \pmod{256}$?

Comment: Successive squaring.

Comment: @T.Bongers It still doesn't seem easy.

Comment: Once you show that $3^{64} \equiv 1 \pmod{256}$, then $27^{1986} = 3^{3 \cdot 1986} = 3^{93 \cdot 64 + 6} \equiv 3^6 \pmod{256}$.

Answer (score 2):

The crucial facts for the solution are:

- You want to compute $27^{1986} \bmod{256}$
- $3^{64} \equiv 1 \bmod{256}$
- $3\cdot1986 \equiv 6 \bmod 64$

These imply that $27^{1986} = 3^{3\cdot1986} \equiv 3^6 = 729 \equiv 217\bmod{256}$.

Answer (score 0):

The last $8$ binary digits represent the residue class of the number $\pmod {100000000_2}$ which in decimal is written $\pmod {256}$.

From the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) we know that $\lambda(256) = 64$ is the maximum order of any number (and the order of every number will divide this), and since $27$ is coprime to $256$, $27^{64}\equiv 1 \bmod 256$. We also see that $1986 = 2 \bmod 64$. So the answer in decimal is

$$27^{1986}\equiv 27^2 \equiv 729\equiv 217\bmod 256
$$

which converts to binary as

$$217_{10} = 11011001_2$$